# Unable to set partitoner to the JobConf object

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

I wrote a custom partitioner but am unable to set it to the `JobConf` object in the main class.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;

public class FirstCharTextPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return (key.toString().charAt(0)) % numReduceTasks;
    }    
}
```

But when I try to set this to the `JobConf` object, I get the following error.
*The method setPartitionerClass(Class) in the type JobConf is not applicable for the arguments (Class)*

```
public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1); 
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                word.set(token);
                output.collect(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> { 
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
        conf.setJobName("wordcount");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setPartitionerClass(FirstCharTextPartitioner.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the **new** `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner`.

You need to implement the old interface `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner`, like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner;

public class FirstCharTextPartitioner implements Partitioner<Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return (key.toString().charAt(0)) % numReduceTasks;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But can you please explain then what is the new Partitioner used for?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore It is the same thing, but abstract class based to fit into the "new" mapreduce API. The old is based on interfaces whereas the new one is based on abstract classes to be more easier extendable for future use.

Comment: So if I want to use the new Partitioner, how do I modify the code?

Comment: Isn't that using the old Partitoner? I meant how do I use  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner which you said was the new one.

Comment: Oh sorry mixed that up, yes the one I linked ist the "old", yours is the new one. For that to use you have to completely use the new API. (Not extending from `MapReduceBase` but from `Mapper` and `Reducer` (classes) directly.